# Can you limit the words between two capturing groups in Regex

Tags: regex, limit

I have been trying to create a parser for Law texts.

I need to find a way to find "external links" like : *art. 45 alin. (1) din Lege nr. 54/2000*

But the problem is that my country law writing style is so, soooo lacking uniformity and that means sometimes the links might look like this : *articolul 45 alineatul (1) din Legeea nr. 30/2000*

The fact that my language has forms for words for days. (*articol, articolului, articolelor....*)

That means that i need to generalize that first thing... (*art.*) as to catch as many forms as possible and pray that the last thing is a law number & year (*54/2000*).

Now here comes the hard part... The problem is that every section that starts with *Articol N* starts the regex and it goes on and on until it finds a law number & year that have absolutely no relation between them.

This is how it looks `\b(((A|a)rt.*?) \(?\d*?\)??)( \w*? )*?nr\.? (\d+\/\d\d\d\d|\d+\/\d\d\d\d)\b`

My question is there a way to limit the words between the two capturing groups?

Link to a Docs to determine what should pass and what not:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vn2HwYaCq8UB1felY1GvfmbTI2w8o5RgW4efD9fsvQM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: With Python you could add `{m, n}` to the group, to capture between m and n instances of that group.

Comment: Hi, can you share which tool (flavor) you are using to apply your regex and also it would be great to have some examples with a "should match" "should not match"

Comment: @JamesMcPherson I have tried instead of `( \w*? )*?` this `( \w*? ){1,10}`, but while using the Regex101 engine, all flavors, I still get entire lines insided the match.
@JorgeCampos I have added a link to a docs to see that should and should not pass.

Comment: Have you tried `\bmy dog\b\s*(?:\w+\s*){0,50}\bhas fleas\b`, where at most 50 words can separate `"my dog"` and `"has fleas"`?

Comment: It worked, thank you..
You were right, James :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cary and James answered in comments above, I used `(?:\S+\s*){0,15}`. I used *\S* instead of *\w* to include punctuation and thus, abbreviated forms of the names of the Law (e.g. *Const.* for *Constitution*). That was the reason why my original regex wasn't working even when using `{m,n}`.